# iPhone - Core Data Bool Values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, boolean

I have a BOOL in my core data.
I want the value to be null unless i set it to either YES, or NO.
Is it possible to do this?
in my code how can i check to see if the value has not been set yet or not?

In my nsmanagedObject i use NSNumber for my BOOL, in my core data mdoel i have BOOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CoreData allows you to set default values.
A Bool can contain "YES", "NO" , "None".
Setting the default value to "None" makes the returned value "null" which is exactly what i needed.

Comment: This is what I was also thinking. In my case I have a node with a hasChildren attribute. If it is None it means I need to query the server to check if that node has children, Yes and No will mean I definitely know whether it does or does not have children.

Comment: For anyone else encountering the same problem as I did... you also need to have the "Use Scalar Type" option unchecked, otherwise the value will default to false.

Answer (score 3):

If you set Boolean as the attribute type in your model, that means it will be implemented using `NSNumber`.

I'm not sure why you'd want to return no value instead of `NO`, I'd actually recommend you don't. You'll have a much easier time with data integrity if you just set a false default value.

However, if you absolutely insist, you can just check if the attribute is `nil` or not to see if it was assigned a value yet.

Comment: There is a difference between NO and "not set" in many use cases.

Comment: I realise that there is a difference. I've been there before and it's bound to introduce integrity problems. I think there are better ways, like using an integer that is either -1, 0, or 1.

Comment: I agree. -1, 0, and 1 are a better solution

Comment: make sure you check the "optional" checkbox otherwise you will just have 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is yes, and there is real meaning to use 'yes' 'no' and a different 'none', which means the data is intact. In Core Data there is good reason sometimes to check against 'none', especially if you'd like to debug a database. In Core Data you can use:

```
[myManagedObject setValue: nil forKey:@"attributeOfMyManagedObject"];
```

and if check your SQL database behind your Core Data you will see 'NULL' if you use default settings.